# Updating a DBML file from the designer class files in LINQ TO SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is there a way to update a dbml file from the designer class file as I have someone who made changes to the designer class files rather than the DBML. Please help

Comment: Not so much AFAIK. You might want to reapply the changes, editing the xml in the dbml instead.

Comment: Thanks Marc .. Just wanted a easier way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Can the changes be moved to a .cs file that has the "other side" of the partial classes from the dbml? Otherwise - no dice.

Comment: I have a modified code file with new tables and relations in the .cs file. I wanted an easier way to reflect those changes in the dbml file. Guess not possible to do it other than manually adding it